# How to focus the last Element in a JQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I use JQuery Ui Autocomplete and position the suggestion box above the input field as shown in the image below. When I use **autoFocus: true** I can set a focus on the first element of the list.

Now, I want that the last element of the list is in focus (i.e., the element which is the closest to the input field). How can I do that? How can I select the last element in the list?

[image]

Javascript:

```
$input.autocomplete({
    source: someUrl,
    minLength: 2,
    autoFocus: true,
    position: { my : "left bottom", at: "left top", collision: "none" }
}); // end autocomplete
```

Comment: provide a jsfiddle. Wouldn't you wish to reverse the item order?

Comment: I updated my question. I want that the Element which is the closest to the input field is selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $input.autocomplete(someUrl, {
        matchContains: true, minChars: 1, scroll:true, autoFill: false, scrollHeight: 240,
        formatItem: function (row, i, max, term) {
            return row.display;
        },
        formatResult: function (row) {
            return row.value;
        },
        displayPosition: "left"
    });
```

Comment: are you sure that this answer is for jquery ui autocomplete?

Comment: YES. Using jQuery autocomplete use here.